# Blocking groups of threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 100 threads. I want to run 10 thread before 10 another threads run and continue to stay of the threads array. Can anybody help me?

Sorry about my English. Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you really need 100 threads? Sounds like what you want is more of a "pool of threads" that you can assign "tasks" to...

Comment: Please explain more exact what you want to do, because simply said - your question mkes no sense logically.

Comment: Hey Hung, are you asking for a way to block 10 threads from running until 10 other (specific) threads have started?

Comment: Why do you need such an exact amount of tasks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will start 10 tasks, and wait for them to complete before starting the next 10 tasks.  One word of caution is that the order in which the set of 10 tasks start is not guaranteed.  That is, this example will block until the set of 10 are finished, but task 1 may start before task 0:

```
private static void Main()
{
   List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
   {
       if (i % 10 == 0)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Waiting for all tasks to complete");
           Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
           Console.WriteLine("All tasks have completed. Continuing...");
           tasks.Clear();
       }

       tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(TrivialTask, new TaskState(i)));
   }
}

public class TaskState
{
    public TaskState(int id)
    {
        TaskId = id;
    }

    public int TaskId { get; set; }
}

private static void TrivialTask(object state)
{
    TaskState taskState = (TaskState) state;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Task " +  taskState.TaskId + " completed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

[Here](http://blog.abodit.com/2010/11/task-parallel-library-a-scheduler-with-priority-apartment-state-and-maximum-degree-of-parallelism/) is an alternative scheduler for it that appears to let you control the degree of parallelism manually.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you can accomplish your task with TPL. Run tasks, wait for their completion with [Task.WaitAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx), run another bunch of tasks, use [ContinueWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) to do something after they finish, still executing other code on, for example, UI thread... Read about it [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Task_Parallelism) and see some source code. There are more articles on [parallel programming](http://www.albahari.com/threading) at Albahari's website. You can read it, its really nice written.